# Parsing & converting nested xml in python

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have below xml data.

```
<transaction>
        <date>20190415</date>
        <ticket>303434037</ticket>
        <value>15</value>
        <notenders>01</notenders>
        <tenderdetail>
            <tendertype>00</tendertype>
            <tenderamt>15</tenderamt>
        </tenderdetail>
        <item>
            <receipeno>00001096</receipeno>
            <price>7</price>
            <qty>0001</qty>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <receipeno>00000786</receipeno>
                    <price>8</price>
                    <qty>0001</qty>
                    <items>
                        <item>
                            <receipeno>00000599</receipeno>
                            <price>0</price>
                            <qty>1</qty>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <receipeno>00000605</receipeno>
                            <price>0</price>
                            <qty>1</qty>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <receipeno>00000608</receipeno>
                            <price>0</price>
                            <qty>0004</qty>
                        </item>
                    </items>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <receipeno>10000043</receipeno>
                    <price>0</price>
                    <qty>0001</qty>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <receipeno>00000381</receipeno>
                    <price>7</price>
                    <qty>0001</qty>
                    <items>
                    <item>
                            <receipeno>00000607</receipeno>
                            <price>0</price>
                            <qty>1</qty>
                        </item>
                    </items>
                </item>
            </items>
        </item>
   </transaction>
```

I need to convert this to a table format. the issues is there are many nested branches inside each tag. eg many `<item>` & `<items>` tags. irrespective of the nested-ness. I need to list down the data one below he other.

my desired output is as follows

```
 +----------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----+
|   date   | ticket | value | notenders | tendertype | tenderamt | receipeno | price | qty |
+----------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----+
| 20190101 |  12345 |    15 |         1 |          0 |        15 |      1096 |     7 |   1 |
| 20190101 |  12345 |    15 |         1 |          0 |        15 |       786 |     8 |   1 |
| 20190101 |  12345 |    15 |         1 |          0 |        15 |       599 |     0 |   1 |
| 20190101 |  12345 |    15 |         1 |          0 |        15 |       605 |     0 |   1 |
| 20190101 |  12345 |    15 |         1 |          0 |        15 |       608 |     0 |   4 |
| 20190101 |  12345 |    15 |         1 |          0 |        15 |       143 |     0 |   1 |
| 20190101 |  12345 |    15 |         1 |          0 |        15 |       381 |     7 |   1 |
| 20190101 |  12345 |    15 |         1 |          0 |        15 |       607 |     0 |   1 |
+----------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----+
```

I'm new to python & XML parsing. Hence, kindly, direct me to solve this.
...

Comment: Try Element Tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from necessary imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import re
```

Then, to remove leading zeroes from tags to be read, define the following function:

```
def stripLZ(src):
    return re.sub(r'^0+(?=\d)', '', src)
```

To read the source file and its root element, execute:

```
tree = et.parse('transaction.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

To read tags from the *root* level (other than read from *item*s), execute:

```
dt = root.find('date').text
tck = root.find('ticket').text
val = root.find('value').text
notend = stripLZ(root.find('notenders').text)
```

Two remaining tags are one level down, so start from reading their parent tag:

```
tdet = root.find('tenderdetail')
```

and read these tags from it:

```
tendtyp = stripLZ(tdet.find('tendertype').text)
tendamt = tdet.find('tenderamt').text
```

Note that I used *stripLZ* function here (it will be used
a few times more).

Now there is time to create the result DataFrame:

```
df_cols = ['date', 'ticket', 'value', 'notenders',
    'tendertype', 'tenderamt', 'receipeno', 'price', 'qty']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = df_cols)
```

And the loading loop can be performed using *iter* method:

```
for it in root.iter('item'):
    rcp = it.find('receipeno').text
    prc = it.find('price').text
    qty = stripLZ(it.find('qty').text)
    df = df.append(pd.Series([dt, tck, val, notend,
        tendtyp, tendamt, rcp, prc, qty],
        index = df_cols), ignore_index=True)
```

This loop:

- Iterates over all *item* tags, regardless if their depth.
- Reads 3 tags from the current *item*.
- Appends a row to the result DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to get all data from nested XML File, but i think there is an elegant way to achieve the result:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_data = 'your xml data'

# Prepare for the list of variable to save XML data
date=[]
ticket=[]
value=[]
notenders=[]
tendertype=[]
tenderamt=[]
receipeno=[]
price=[]
qty=[]

# Parse the XML File to get the desired data
root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
# Get header data from XML (date, ticket, value, notenders, tenderdetail)
date.append(root.find('date').text)
ticket.append(root.find('ticket').text)
value.append(root.find('value').text)
notenders.append(int(root.find('notenders').text))
nested_node0=root.findall('tenderdetail')
for child0 in nested_node0:
    tendertype.append(int(child0.find('tendertype').text))
    tenderamt.append(int(child0.find('tenderamt').text))
# Get all data under first item tag
nested_node1 = root.findall('item') #1
for child in nested_node1:
    receipeno.append(int(child.find('receipeno').text))
    price.append(int(child.find('price').text))
    qty.append(int(child.find('qty').text))

    # Get all data under first items tag
    nested_node2 = child.findall('items') #2
    for child2 in nested_node2:
        # Get all data under second item tag
        nested_node3 = child2.findall('item') #3
        for child3 in nested_node3:
            receipeno.append(int(child3.find('receipeno').text))
            price.append(int(child3.find('price').text))
            qty.append(int(child3.find('qty').text))
            # Get all data under second items tag
            nested_node4 = child3.findall('items') #4
            for child4 in nested_node4:
                # Get all data under third item tag
                nested_node5 = child4.findall('item') #5
                for child5 in nested_node5:
                    receipeno.append(int(child5.find('receipeno').text))
                    price.append(int(child5.find('price').text))
                    qty.append(int(child5.find('qty').text))

# Make the same length of every list of data with the max length
date.extend([np.nan]*(len(receipeno)-len(date)))
ticket.extend([np.nan]*(len(receipeno)-len(ticket)))
value.extend([np.nan]*(len(receipeno)-len(value)))
notenders.extend([np.nan]*(len(receipeno)-len(notenders)))
tendertype.extend([np.nan]*(len(receipeno)-len(tendertype)))
tenderamt.extend([np.nan]*(len(receipeno)-len(tenderamt)))
data={'date':date,
      'ticket':ticket,
      'value':value,
      'notenders':notenders,
      'tendertype':tendertype,
      'tenderamt':tenderamt,
      'receipeno': receipeno,
      'price': price,
      'qty':qty}

# Create DataFrame from data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
df
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: This works great.. yeah, I hope someone could give us an elegant & more pythonic solution.